# Azure Point-to-site VPN routing

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

I've set up Point-to-Site VPN to one of my multiple VNets. When I connect from my machine, I can access the VNet which gateway belongs to. But how can I set up routing, so I can access all other VNets (having VNet-to-VNet gateways working)?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up PEERING.  Set up peering on the existing real vnets to allow peering by the vpn subnet.  Then make sure to allow traffic in your NSG.

Comment: What do you mean by Peering?